# Have class assertion does not work in my case

Tags: cypress

I need to verify that class dot-green is in the element. I use this code and it does not work:

```
        cy.get('.product-create-left-items', { timeout: 10000 }).contains('Po objednání').siblings().should((dotColor) => {
        expect(dotColor).to.have.class('dot-green')
        expect(dotColor).to.not.have.class('dot')
      })
```

Html looks like this:

```
<div class="product-create-left-items">
    <ul>
        <li class="li-pointer" onclick="changeDiv(0)">
                <div class="product-create-left-item">
                    Založení produktu
                </div>
                <div id="create-1" class="dot-green"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="li-pointer" onclick="changeDiv(1)">
                <div class="product-create-left-item">
                        Po objednání
                </div>
                <div id="create-2" class="dot-green"></div>
                </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the exact error message you receive?

Comment: The problem is not reproducible, your test runs without any error.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any error with the code block above.
If the error still persists, you can try this

```
 cy.get('.product-create-left-items', { timeout: 10000 }).contains('Po objednání').siblings().then(() => {

            cy.get('div').should('have.class', 'dot-green')
            cy.get('div').should('not.have.class', 'dot')
})
```